# can't stop or restart the thin gem on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get the below error whenever I try to stop or restart the thin gem on Ubuntu 10.04. Any fix for this?

```
Can't stop process, no PID found in tmp/pids/thin.pid
```

Comment: Is the server running or not? Can you post the last contents of the thin log file?

Answer (score 0):

```
pgrep 'thin';

echo <pid> > /tmp/pids/thin.pid
```

Essentially the problem is your PID file is empty for whatever reason. So use pgrep/ps to find the PID, and stick it in the PID file.